# highlight multiple dateranges from jsonArray datepicker (jquery)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to highlight multiple dateranges, but so far only one seems to work.
If any other information is required, please ask. new to this.
Thanks in advance!

jquery script I'm currently using:

```
var testJson = [{
    "startDate": "2015, 5, 1",
        "endDate": "2015, 5, 4"
}, {
    "startDate": "2015, 5, 4",
        "endDate": "2015, 5, 11"
}];

$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        for(var i = 0; i < testJson.length; i++) {
            startDate = new Date(testJson[i].startDate);
            endDate = new Date(testJson[i].endDate);

            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-error', 'Gereserveerd!'];
            }

            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a typo! I should have placed the '`return`' outside the loop, like below:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        for(var i = 0; i < testJson.length; i++) {
            startDate = new Date(testJson[i].startDate);
            endDate = new Date(testJson[i].endDate);

            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-error', 'Gereserveerd!'];
            }

            //return [true, '', ''];
        }
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
});
```